# SQL : If more than one unique key, corresponding value should be null

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
email_1          | name_1   | email_2             | name_2 
+----------------+----------+---------------------+----------
sandy@name.com   | Sandy    | sandy@name.com      | Sandy 
sandy@name.com   | Sandy    | sandy@name.com      | Pat 
chris@name.com   | Chris    |                     | 
george@name.com  | George   | george@name.com     | Shelly 
george@name.com  | George   | george@name.com     | George 
hank@name.com    | Hank     | hank@name.com       | Barbara
hank@name.com    | Hank     | hank@name.com       | Hank
mikey@name.com   | Mikey    |                     |
```

I have multiple names for the same email address. For email addresses with more than one name, I would like to create a table that lists the distinct email and `Null` for the name. Emails that are attached to only one name, retain the name.

Resulting Table:

```
email            | name   
+----------------+----------+
sandy@name.com   |          | 
chris@name.com   | Chris    |                      
george@name.com  |          |
hank@name.com    |          |
mikey@name.com   | Mikey    |
```

How would I write a query to do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You want to unpivot and aggregate:

```
select email,
       (case when min(name) = max(name) then min(name) end) as name
from ((select email_1 as email, name_1 as name from t
      ) union all
      (select email_2 as email, name_2 as name from t
      )
     ) e
group by email;
```